# The second dual of $C(X)$ with the compact-open topology

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-algebras, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Then $C(X)$ is a Banach algebra with the supremum norm and so is $A=C(X)^{**}$ under either Arens product. Moreover, it is easy to verify that $A\cong C(Z)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $Z$ (for example, it is commutative and satisfies the C*-condition, so the Gelfand-Naimark theorem applies). Alternatively, it may be represented as $L_\infty(\mu)$ for some non-separable measure $\mu$.

I was wondering if a similar descriptions are available when $X$ is only a **completely regular space** and $C(X)$ is considered under the **topology of uniform convergence on compact sets** (the compact-open topology). In this case, $C(X)$ is still a locally convex topological algebra. Is there any sensible description of $C(X)^{**}$ in this case?

Any references to the literature will be appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but just a remark: if you endow ∗ with the **topology of uniform convergence on compact sets** (similarly to $C(X)$), then $C(X)^{∗∗}=C(X)$ for each paracompact locally compact space $X$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_algebra

Comment: @user124775 Which topology would you like to use on $C(X)^*$ in order to define $C(X)^{**}$? If it is the weak-* topology, then you will get back $C(X)$ no matter what. So do you want the strong dual topology?

Comment: @RobertFurber, it is customary to use the strong topology when discussing the second dual of a lcHs. Otherwise, everything is trivial as you say.

Comment: This might be of interest.  Samuel Kaplan made a detailed study of the second dual of $C(K)$ for $K$ compact.  His results were documented in a series of substantial articles and a monograph. These are easily traceable.  A student of his, C. Shannon, extended his investigations to the case of the lcs of continuous functions on a completely regular space in her dissertation,   which was the basis of the article  „The second dual of $C(X)$“ in Pac. J. Math.  72 (1977) 237-253.